# Window interface snap window

Tags: window, interface

Basically when I try snap window to the left or right and move it up/down or snap to the top and move it left/right,   I have something that can be described as invisible border moves and erases content of the window. Is it suppose to be like this?

Comment: are you on KDE?

Comment: Can you provide more information about this issue - if possible a video or screen shot of it in action?

Comment: If you are using 11.04, there is a new plug-in that maximizes windows when you drag them to this sides of the screen, like aero snap.

Comment: i'm in Unity. 11.04.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ypMwZ50QIWg   There is a link on it.  It does not affect functionality or anything like this, it just looks weird and wrong...

Comment: today's updates fixed the issue! :-)

Answer (score 2):

As per a comment:

> > Todays update fixed the issue